# Cannot use numpy, pandas, matplotlib on my new mac

Tags: python, macos

I just changed my computer and it seems like I cannot run my machine learning code anymore. Here are some examples:

**main.py file**

```
import matplotlib
...
...
```

**command**

```
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Here is just one example of matplotlib. Although I can found this module in `pip list`, I cannot successfullt plot the graph. Anyone knows why?

Comment: you might have multiple python environments on your computer. This would explain why matplotlib shows up in pip list, but isn't accessible to your program.

Comment: Create a virtualenv  then activate and use it.

Comment: @user1558604 Okay. So is there any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: just check `python -V` and check if there is a python3 using `which python3` or `which python3.7` or `which python3.8`

Comment: @Shijith Thanks! ```python -V``` -> ```Python 2.7.16```; ```which python3``` -> ```/usr/bin/python3```;  Is this normal?

Comment: ok use `python3 main.py` to execute your files

Comment: @Shijith Same output...Module Not Found.

Comment: It actually works fine for matplotlib right now. But now for ```from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit```. It says ```ImportError: No module named sklearn.model_selection```

Comment: use pip3 to install libraries

Comment: it is better to use anaconda / minconda , as it it easy to create environment for different libraries/ python versions

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor... before you start installing things and creating symlinks, go install Homebrew. Once you have that installed, use it to install Python3 (it should install under `/usr/local/bin`). Once that is set, open your `.bash_profile` ($HOME/.bash_profile`) and add to the end:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Now the Homebrew version of your Python binaries will be found first.

Apple has added an "extra special feature" to MacOS called *System Integrity Protection* which prevents you from being able to edit / replace files in certain locations, which includes `/usr/bin`. This means you can't go in there and replace the default Python2 binaries with something newer. Only option is to do what I've suggested, or something similar (well, that or just live with Python2, but that's not a very good option).

EDIT:
Please do not install anaconda **and** Python from Homebrew (I personally do not like Anaconda, YYMV). Go with one or the other, or unpleasant library conflicts surely will be in your future.